# How to read a directory name within a bash script

Tags: shell

I'm extracting a tar file within a shell script and it is is creating folder with a name like:

supportsuite-5-20-3/

The "supportsuite" part of the name is always the same, but I don't know what the remaining characters are in advance.  I'm unpacking the tar file in a script and I need the name of the resulting folder from within that script.  What is the best way to put that directory name into a shell variable within the script after the tar has been extracted?

I'm script challenged, so thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're assuming that all of the files in the tar file are in the same directory, you could do something like:

```
DIRNAME=$(tar -tvf $TARFILE  | head -1 | sed -e 's:^.* \([^/]*\)/.*$:\1:')
```

Note that it will probably misbehave if your filenames have spaces in them. If you care about this you'll need to adjust the regex in the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

This will unzip it and keep the folder name in tact.

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar" -exec tar -xv '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of a hack, but this might help (written for `bash`:

```
tar zxf supportsuite-5-20-3.tgz
NEWDIR=$(cd supportsuite-* && pwd)
```

Comment: Could do just NEWDIR="supportsuite-*" Though both approaches assumes theres one and only one directory starting with supportsuite- in the current directory.